# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /spec (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Running simple command

```
rails g model User
```

leads to:

```
→ bundle exec rails g model User
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160128191020_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/user_spec.rb
      invoke      factory_girl
      create        /spec/factories/users.rb
/Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /spec (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:61:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `call'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/generators/factory_girl/model/model_generator.rb:46:in `create_factory_file'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/generators/factory_girl/model/model_generator.rb:25:in `create_fixture_file'
```

rest is omitted.

I'm using **factory girls rails**. `spec` and `spec/factories folders`' permissions are **drwxr-xr-x (755, change to 777 had no effect)**. Re installation of `factory_girl_rails` had no effect. `Ruby 2.2.2` (tried different versions already)

[Tired this, no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147510/errnoeaccess-permission-denied-dir-s-mkdir)

Comment: `/spec/factories/users.rb` is the problem, it is trying to create the `spec` dir under the root dir. But why so happening ? :)

Comment: Any chance that you set a value for 'FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths'?  It looks as though the value '/spec/factories' has overridden 'spec/factories' (ie., root level rather than relative to the current folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did:

```
# config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "/spec/factories"
end
```

If so, you need to change it from "/spec/factories" to "spec/factories"

Reference: https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/config/application.rb

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions to access the required directory for the system root user

```
sudo chmod 777 -R your_project_directory_to_be_access
```

In your case you can use:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /spec/
```

For security reasons, just keep in your mind:

`chmod 777` gives everybody read, write and execute rights which for most problems is definitively too much.