# how to fix Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, mkdir

when I tried bundle install

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -
/Users/noah/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/2.7.0/racc-1.5.2
An error occurred while installing racc (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

this thing keeps happening..
how can i solve this...?

Comment: Please update with `gem environment`

Comment: didn't worked...

Comment: Please update the ticket description with what `gem environment` returns.

Comment: A similar issue is in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147510/errnoeaccess-permission-denied-dir-s-mkdir see if it helps you

Comment: solved!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `rbenv`.

This command from the linked [SoF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147510/errnoeaccess-permission-denied-dir-s-mkdir) solves it.

```bash
sudo chown -R <your_user> $HOME/.rbenv
```